# Why Qt serial read data never arrives? (Qt 5.15.2, C++, Win64, MSVC2019_64)

Tags: c++, asynchronous, serial-port, qt5, terminal-emulator

To develop my program first without connecting two physical machines on serial port, I downloaded and used this program to simulate COM ports:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/
I connected virtual COM4 to virtual COM5. It works fine.

Using Br@y's Terminal program, I tested if I connect to COM4 in one Terminal instance, and to COM5 in another instance on the same computer, the data that I send on one terminal arrives in the other terminal, and vice versa.
Terminal program: https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/

Now let's see the problem:
I used SerialPortReader class from this official Qt sample code for async serial read: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtserialport.git/tree/examples/serialport/creaderasync
It connects to COM5 and sets baud rate to 9600 successfully, but no data arrives if I send something via Terminal to COM4, so: SerialPortReader runs through with no error, but after then, no matter what message I send on my Terminal instance, handleReadyRead, handleError, and handleTimeout never get called.

(If I have already a terminal emulator connected to the virtual COM5 port, then connection in my C++ program fails, so indeed the open() check works fine.
Also, if I try to send more than one messages to my program via the virtual COM4 port, Terminal freezes, which is a clear sign of that the previous message has not yet been read on the other side(COM5).)

I have googled a lot, but have not yet found any solutions. Someone here said that it is/was a bug [Qt Serial Port Errors - Data not getting read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868788/qt-serial-port-errors-data-not-getting-read) and that the problem is in qserialport_win.cpp, but even if I change that and compile my program again, nothing happens.
I use the following code to create the class, but the class' content is unchanged, I use it as I found in the sample program:

```
    // Serial comm init
    QSerialPort serialPort;
    QString serialPortName = "COM5";
    serialPort.setPortName(serialPortName);

    int serialPortBaudRate = 9600;
    

    if (serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        if(serialPort.setBaudRate(serialPortBaudRate) &&
            serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8) &&
            serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity) &&
            serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop) &&
            serialPort.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl)) {
            //SerialPortReader serialPortReader(&serialPort);
            SerialPortReader serialPortReader(&serialPort, this);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed to set COM connection properties " << serialPortName.toStdString() << serialPort.errorString().toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to open port " << serialPortName.toStdString() << serialPort.errorString().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I see local variables which lifetime ends sooner then any data can be received. I expect something like this: `auto* serialPort = new QSerialPort(this);` and some code which connects signals and slots which will react on incoming data.

Comment: A "Minimal, Reproducible Example" would help a lot...
@MarekR I agree. Additionally, I assume that the lifetime of ``serialPortReader`` is also a big issue here.

Comment: If you use QSerialPort::NoFlowControl then it is up to you to turn on the handshake lines, setDataTerminalReady() and setRequestToSend().  If that works, the vast majority of devices need them, then you very heavily favor QSerialPort::HardwareControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I figured out a sketchy but working version:

SerialPortReader.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QTimer>

class SerialPortReader : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SerialPortReader(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SerialPortReader() override;
    void close();

private:
    QSerialPort *serialPort = nullptr;
    QByteArray m_readData;
    QTimer m_timer;

public slots:
    void handleReadyRead();
    //void handleTimeout();
    //void handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error);

};
```

SerialPortReader.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SerialPortReader.h"

SerialPortReader::SerialPortReader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

    serialPort = new QSerialPort(this);
    const QString serialPortName = "COM4"; //argumentList.at(1);
    serialPort->setPortName(serialPortName);

    const int serialPortBaudRate = QSerialPort::Baud9600;
    serialPort->setBaudRate(serialPortBaudRate);

    if (!serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open port" << std::endl;
        //return 1;
    }


    std::cout << "SerialPortReader(QSerialPort *serialPort, QObject *parent)" << std::endl;

    connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(handleReadyRead()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

   // connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &SerialPortReader::handleReadyRead);
    //connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::errorOccurred, this, &SerialPortReader::handleError);
    //connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &SerialPortReader::handleTimeout);

    //m_timer.start(5000);
}

void SerialPortReader::handleReadyRead()
{
    std::cout << "handleReadyRead()" << std::endl;

    m_readData.append(serialPort->readAll());

    if (!m_timer.isActive())
        m_timer.start(5000);
}

/*
void SerialPortReader::handleTimeout()
{
    std::cout << "handleTimeout()" << std::endl;

    if (m_readData.isEmpty()) {
        std::cout << "No data was currently available for reading" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Data successfully received" << std::endl;
        //m_standardOutput << m_readData << Qt::endl;
    }

    //QCoreApplication::quit();
}

void SerialPortReader::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError serialPortError)
{
    std::cout << "handleError()" << std::endl;

    if (serialPortError == QSerialPort::ReadError) {
        std::cout << "An I/O error occurred while reading" << std::endl;
        //QCoreApplication::exit(1);
    }
}
*/

SerialPortReader::~SerialPortReader() {
    close();
}

// Close the files, filestreams, etc
void SerialPortReader::close() {
    // ...
}
```

... and in my QApplication code you just need to include the .h and write this to instantiate the serial listener:

```
SerialPortReader *serialPortReader = new SerialPortReader(this);
```